# Prove that every point on a line AC that isn't C, precedes C in the direction AC.

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to prove that every point on a line segment AC that isn't the point C, precedes C in the direction AC.

> My attempt:
> A and C are both extremities of AC. A precedes C in the direction AC. The extremities of a line must be the first and final point in a given direction, otherwise they are not extremities. Since A precedes C in the direction AC, C cannot be the first point and so must be the final point. Then since C is the last point to occur on AC in the direction AC and so every other point on AC precedes it.

I'm not sure if this proof is correct, I think I'm unsure about whether certain things are true by definition or if I need to prove them. Also, I don't know if 'A precedes C in the direction AC' is just true by definition of the direction AC or if I need to prove this statement. Could you please tell me if this is so and also if the proof is correct or not. Thank you.

Comment: How do you define a segment?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I don't know. Would 'finite in both directions' count as a definition?

Comment: If you don't know you cannot answer that question. Usually a segment is defined as "all the points on line $AB$ lying between $A$ and $B$, plus $A$ and $B$", where a point $P$ is between $A$ and $B$ if it follows $A$ and precedes $B$, or the other way around.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca ok, that's how I define it then. Is the proof right?

Comment: In that case no proof is needed, that's true by definition.

Comment: Your proof is correct but a little wordy because like us, you are wondering what to prove. The proof is simpler. A line segment from $A$ to $C$ starts at $A$ and ends at $C$. Therefore, every point on the line precedes $C$ because to end on a point means it comes last.